# If WebException

Tags: vb.net, webclient

With the following code:

```
            Dim address2 As String = "blablabla"
            Dim client2 As WebClient = New WebClient()
            Dim reader2 As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client2.OpenRead(address2))
            Dim json2 As JObject = JObject.Parse(reader2.ReadToEnd)
            If FlatLabel4.Text = "Nível: 30" Then
```

I want him to, if "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.", it does something.

How can i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to learn how to handle exceptions in VB.NET:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289505(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: HttpWebRequest / HttpWebResponse will allow you to examine the http response code.